# How to re-access my investments if a national disaster happens?

Tags: investing, mutual-funds, natural-disasters

There is no disaster for now. But I got curious what should I do when local disasters(like war, earthquake, etc) happen where I live(I live in South Korea btw).

Let's say I got a disaster, survived, and immigrated to another country. I invested most of my money in multiple mutual funds via fund platform. Some mutual funds are investing globally and indirectly, so some of my investments might be still left. I got to access my investment, but the fund platform I used must be devastated by the disaster.

How to re-access my investments if a national disaster happens?

While I mentioned my country, answers are no need to be region specific.

Comment: The question is highly hypothetical; in it's current form it will attract opinionated answers. If you have a specific scenario in mind, it would help.

Comment: @Ironluca I don't know... If I am too specific, it might less helpful to others and future me. But I'll consider it.

Comment: @Ironluca Sadly, this question is started just from my imagination, which might not happen. So, it might be hard to add some details other than my current investments.

Comment: The record of your ownership could be in multiple places - your own records, the trading platform, and the fund company should all have records. Depending on where the disaster hits, what records are destroyed, what backups exist, etc. there could be a number of ways to claim ownership.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not familiar with the securities and banking regulations in South Korea, but often the regulations require investment firms to have disaster recovery procedures.  Another safety check is that you have been given a statement of your account, so worst case, the liquidator can see from your statement that you hold certain assets and return them to you.

Furthermore, many securities regulations provide some form of 'insurance' against your broker being unable to give you back your assets.  In the US there is SIPC insurance which covers up to $500,000 of securities in your account - though there have been instances where countries have been unable to pay or refused to pay (Iceland).

Perhaps a worse risk is if the country was invaded, the new (occupying) government could then pass a law granting them ownership of all assets held by the country's citizens.  You could hold your assets off-shore, but you also have to be certain that the off-shore country is not subject to such risk.  This is part of the reason why Switzerland has been popular.